# Calculate approximative block height at a certain time?

Tags: blocks, timestamp

What would be a formula for calculating the block height at a certain point in time, approximative
How would I calculate the block height for a date like next Christmas 0h midnight?

Answer (score 8):

If you just mean a general formula, rather than something written in Solidity...

Something along the lines of:

`last_block_number + ((future_time - time_now) / block_time)`

Where the `future_time` and `time_now` are in seconds since the epoch, and `block_time` is the average expected block time.

The block time is currently hovering between [14 and 14.5 seconds](https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime).

---

So, for example, using a [current](http://www.epochconverter.com/) epoch time of `1481214124`, the epoch time of `1482537600` for midnight Christmas Eve, and the last block of `2771338`:

`2771338 + ((1482537600 - 1481214124) / 14) = 2865872`